# What's the difference between console.log and response.write?

Tags: node.js, terminal, console.log, response.write

With the exception of using console.log to print what's received from a request and response.write to echo a request back, these two seem to essentially do the same thing (echo data back to me). Thanks in advance!

Comment: One writes to the console, the other writes to the response.  The fact that you happen to be reading both is immaterial.  They are two different places to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` puts the data on the standard output (file descriptor number 1).

`response.write` write the data on the `response` object, whatever it is. In your case it seems to be a response to an HTTP request, but it may be any other stream (including standard output).

The results of both of those commands can end up in the same place - like your screen - but taking a different path to the same destination: `console.log` doesn't use the network in the process but `response.write` (most likely) does. I say "most likely" because it is not clear from your question what this `response` is a response to.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm working with streams and saw that both can be used, but wasn't sure how. Thanks for parsing it out.